# Can't seem to get onclick to work, javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick, calculator

I am new to Javascript, I followed a simple tutorial to create a novice calculator, however I can't get it to work and don't understand why not.

It should be displaying the results in an alert box, and it is not.

Any help/input is much appreciated,

Thank you

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var a,b, result;
 funciton setValues()
{
a = Number(document.getElementById("a").value);
b = Number(document.getElementById("b").value);
}
function sum() {
  setValues();
  result = a+b;
  alert("The sume is equel to "+result);
}
function rest()
{
    setValues();
    result = a-b;
    alert("The result is equal to "+result);
}
function mult()
{
    setValues();
    result = a*b;
    alert ("The result is equal to "+result);
}
function div()
{
    setValues();
    result = a/b;
    alert ("The result is equal to "+result);
}

  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input id="a" type="text"/>
        <input id="b" type="text"/>
        <button type="button" onclick="sum()">+</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="rest()">-</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="mult()"> *</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="div()"> /</button>

    </div>


</body>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I would like some help/ input on why the results of the calculator are not displaying in an alert box as they should.

Comment: do notice that you have `onlcick`instead of `onclick`

Comment: check spellings funciton, onlcick

Comment: yes noticed it too, changed it, but still not getting an alert box

Comment: @meztli: the very first step is to open your browser's developer console. This will notify you of things like syntax errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

spelling of **function** in `funciton setValues()` is incorrect.

Also Spelling of onclick is incorrect.

```
Line 39:<button type="button" onlcick="sum()">+</button>
```

That's the only mistake(s), rest of the code is perfect.

Answer (score 2):

One of them is spelled "onlcick", that one for sure isn't working. That might be why your validation is failing. Did you try it anyways? Let us know if you did or didn't, and whether or not fixing the typo helps.

Edit: You also misspelled function as "funcition" above, as well, which is probably causing some of the trouble as well.

Answer (score 0):

you spelled onclick wrong in your addition button